# How do I prevent a indent on a custom Section paragraph

Tags: latex

I have following Latex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\indexentry}[1]{
    \normalsize
    {\vspace{5mm}\Large\textbf{#1}\vspace{5mm}}\\*
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
} 

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{blub}
    \blindtext

    \subsection{foo}
    \blindtext

    \subsection{bar}
    \blindtext

    \subsection{baz}
    \blindtext

    \indexentry{test}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Somehow I get a indent in the paragraph following my custom \indexentry{} Section like this:

[image: custom section indent image]

How do I prevent this?

I already added \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} to prevent this on other paragraphs, but it doesn't seem to affect my custom section paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `%` at the end of some lines. These unprotected line endings are otherwise interpreted as spaces and what you see is not an indention (that's why `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` does not work), but an accumulation of several spaces.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\indexentry}[1]{%
    \normalsize%
    {\vspace{5mm}\Large\textbf{#1}\vspace{5mm}}\\*%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
} 

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{blub}
    \blindtext

    \subsection{foo}
    \blindtext

    \subsection{bar}
    \blindtext

    \subsection{baz}
    \blindtext

    \indexentry{test}%
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a different approach of the `indexentry` function:

```latex
\newcommand{\indexentry}[1]{
    \normalsize
    \section*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i have the same problem with some other things, which are solved with @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 's answer